# How to extract elements from a complex list in Python

Tags: python

I have a list like this:

```
ls = {
    'info': {
        'id': '237371250',
        'market': 'BCH-PERP',
        'future': 'BCH-PERP',
        'side': 'sell',
        'type': 'stop',
        'orderPrice': None,
        'triggerPrice': '104.2',
        'size': '83.33',
        'status': 'open',
        'createdAt': '2022-07-16T12:25:02.288247+00:00',
        'triggeredAt': None,
        'orderId': None,
        'error': None,
        'reduceOnly': True,
        'trailValue': None,
        'trailStart': None,
        'cancelledAt': None,
        'cancelReason': None,
        'retryUntilFilled': True,
        'orderType': 'market',
        'filledSize': '0.0',
        'avgFillPrice': None},
    'id': '237371250',
    'clientOrderId': None,
    'timestamp': 1657974302288,
    'datetime': '2022-07-16T12:25:02.288Z',
    'lastTradeTimestamp': None,
    'symbol': 'BCH/USD:USD',
    'type': 'stop',
    'timeInForce': None,
    'postOnly': None,
    'reduceOnly': True,
    'side': 'sell',
    'price': 104.2,
    'stopPrice': 104.2,
    'amount': 83.33,
    'cost': 0.0,
    'average': None,
    'filled': 0.0,
    'remaining': 83.33,
    'status': 'open',
    'fee': None,
    'trades': [],
    'fees': []}
```

I would like to extract the `'triggerPrice'` value of `104.2` from it. How would I go about doing that?

I have tried `ls['triggerPrice']` but that returns an error.

Any information about what kind of data structure this is and how to access its elements would be gratefully received.

Comment: You're dealing with `dict` objects, not `list`s. Use `ls['info']['triggerPrice']` - `triggerPrice` is inside a nested `dict`.

Comment: thanks for the info. Much appreciated. New to python.

Comment: Dictionaries are covered in the official Python tutorial here: [Dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). I strongly recommend doing a tutorial (though not necessarily that one) before asking more questions here, cause there are lots of things that could be confusing, and if you don't have a good basis, we could end up just confusing you more. Thankfully this question's straightforward, but things like encoding and indentation for example are a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This datastructure is called a **dictionary** (`dict`) and it works the same way as JSON, just the types are Pythonic.

E.g.:
A typical JSON file would be like this

```json
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": null,
    "is_allowed": false
}
```

in python it would be something like this

```py
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": None,
    "is_allowed": False,
}
```

As you can see, only the types are changed.

To access elements in a dictionary,
you just put the name of the dict,
e.g. `ls`,
then lookup a value in the dict with a key:
`ls["id"]`

The solution to your question will be `ls["info"]["triggerPrice"]`